# CMR Font selection and fancy header formatting?

Tags: fonts, header-footer, color, computer-modern, roman

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Chapters like "Chapter1" in CMCSC10 font between two thin lines
After that Chapter name like "Introduction" in CMR17 font
The paragraph body in CMR12 font

I am looking to create a format as in the document
[here](http://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/16375/1/PhDthesis_StefanHommes.pdf).

Also I need to write the header and footer in a very small weight say 8 , with a faded offwhite color in italics.

My Class file looks like this

```
% report classs for writing thesis
\ProvidesClass{mtechthesis}[2015/05/16 Thesis class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{report}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}


% To use graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
% My Images folder
\graphicspath{{myimages/}}
% To put images between text and positioning
\usepackage{float}

%% paper margins
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25 mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\mdseries\Huge}
  {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {3ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

My Main tex file looks like this..

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mtechthesis}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\tiny \textit{My Thesis title}}


% footer page number
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\small \textit{My universityname}}

%header footer font size not working
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\title{
{My thesis Title}\\
{\large University name}\\
{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Logo.jpg}}
}

\author{My Name}
\date{May 2015}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%%unnumbered chapters
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}

I express my, gratitude

\tableofcontents

% Paragraph spacing and indent
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


% including chapters from chapters folder

%chapter1
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/1intro}

%chapter2
\chapter{SDN Architecture}
\input{chapters/2sdnarchitecture}

%chapter3
\chapter{Openflow}
\input{chapters/3Openflow}


\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\input{chapters/Appendix}

\end{document}
```

I am new to latex. Please tell me how to modify my class file so as the mentioned specifications and effects takes place.

Comment: Start by providing us with a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). At this point it is not even clear what format you are using.

Comment: Oh my, that looks like `fncychap`.

Comment: Is the `mtechthesis` class provided by the institution you're writing your thesis at? If so, I don't think you should try and modify the typographic aspect of it. In any case, it's impossible to help without a pointer to the class.

Comment: Hi No mtechthesis class is created by me as you can see above. I have created it to put things bit organised. there are two files above you can see. i have called the same class in my tex file as above again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide MWE then I started with plain TeX example. All specifications (you mentioned) are implemented here.

```
\input opmac

\font\smcaps=cmcsc10 \regfont\smcaps
\def\printchap#1{\vfil\break
  \headline={\hfil\global\headline={\printheadline}}
  \gdef\headtext{#1}
  \vglue 30pt
  \hrule
  \line{\smcaps\thefontsize[17]\vrule height22pt depth10pt width0pt \hfil
    \mtext{chap} \dotocnum{\thechapnum}}
  \hrule
  \vskip20pt
  {\typosize[17/22]\rm \hfill #1\nbpar}\mark{}%
  \nobreak \vskip2cm \firstnoindent
}
\typosize[12/14]

\def\printheadline{\localcolor\Grey\bi\thefontsize[8]\the\pageno\ 
   \hfil\ \headtext\unskip}

\chap Introduction

This is first chapter
\vfil\break

Next page where the headline occurs...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
  adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
  libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\bye
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to accomplish that using a class file. I have updated the code approach am following. I Used titlesec have got similar result but not of all the specifications yet.

Comment: @Curi0usM3 Your actualized post includes MWE from which implies that you are looking for LaTeX solution. This wasn't clear from previous version of your post. Setting exactly a specified typographical design in LaTeX is much more complicated than in plain TeX because there is many times more registers and control sequences you need to control. I can only say: good luck. Thanks for your acceptation of my answer but I hope that you will do re-acceptation when LaTeX solution occurs here.